# How to get the latest payment status based from a selected original payment record in a table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

**The Problem:** How to get the latest payment status based from a selected original payment record in a table

**The Scenario:** The part of the program where I'm currently concerned is regarding the management of balances of client payments.

The program I'm working with is hanging when I'm selecting a particular record of an original payment information and that selected record leads a sequence of records through a foreign key in a particular MySQL table `installation_sales` which is `ref_isales_id` (a foreign key that references a primary key `isales_id` in the same table `installation_sales`.

So, it's a table containing payments of clients where the original payment record of a particular client is the first part of a pattern for the upcoming payments (which are balance payments) with the same client.

**Note:** All variables are already assigned whether here in the block of code or not.

**The Code:**

```
private void manageBalancesTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                 
    payBtn.setEnabled(true);
    historyBtn.setEnabled(true);
    try{
        int row = manageBalancesTable.getSelectedRow();
        clickedTable = (manageBalancesTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        conn = MySQLConnect.ConnectDB();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select isales_id,rce,total_payment,pay_status,pay_amount,remaining_bal,it_id,client_id,ic_id,ref_isales_id from installation_sales where (isales_id='"+clickedTable+"' or ref_isales_id='"+clickedTable+"') and pay_status!='full payment' order by isales_id desc limit 1");

        if(rs.next()) {
            isales_id=rs.getString("isales_id");
            rce=rs.getString("rce");
            total_payment=rs.getDouble("total_payment");
            pay_status=rs.getString("pay_status");
            pay_amount1=rs.getDouble("pay_amount");
            remaining_bal=rs.getDouble("remaining_bal");
            it_id=rs.getInt("it_id");
            client_id=rs.getString("client_id");
            ic_id=rs.getString("ic_id");
            ref_isales_id=rs.getString("ref_isales_id");
        }
        /* When I insert this while looping part in the code, the program lags when I run it. */
        while (!"0".equals(ref_isales_id)) {
            st2 = conn.createStatement();
            rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select isales_id,rce,total_payment,pay_status,pay_amount,remaining_bal,it_id,client_id,ic_id,ref_isales_id from installation_sales where ref_isales_id='"+isales_id+"' and pay_status!='full payment'  order by isales_id desc limit 1");
            if(rs2.next()) {
                isales_id=rs.getString("isales_id");
                rce=rs.getString("rce");
                total_payment=rs.getDouble("total_payment");
                pay_status=rs.getString("pay_status");
                pay_amount1=rs.getDouble("pay_amount");
                remaining_bal=rs.getDouble("remaining_bal");
                it_id=rs.getInt("it_id");
                client_id=rs.getString("client_id");
                ic_id=rs.getString("ic_id");
                ref_isales_id=rs.getString("ref_isales_id");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManageBalancesPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if(null!=pay_status) switch (pay_status) {
        case "reservation fee":
            paymentStatusComboBox.removeAllItems();
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("select payment status...");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("down payment");
            paymentAmountTextField.setText("");
            break;
        case "down payment":
            paymentStatusComboBox.removeAllItems();
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("select payment status...");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("installment");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("full payment");
            paymentAmountTextField.setText("");
            break;
        case "installment":
            paymentStatusComboBox.removeAllItems();
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("select payment status...");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("installment");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("full payment");
            paymentAmountTextField.setText("");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

It's my first time here and any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all net beans/java stuff for now and focus on the sql. For that, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry This block of code is similar to my code when I view history of payments for one particular client when I clicked a selected original payment record and it is working, btw, prior to only lagging, there's an output message ".....too many connections" mysql stuff.

Comment: Absolutely; ignoring my suggestion is your prerogative.

Comment: Haha! Of course! But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that by

```
rs2 = st2.executeQuery(...)
```

inside your while loop you always get the same response and only look at the first entry of what is returned. So you always say: give me [1,2,3,4], look at [1], ask for [1,2,3,4] and look at [1] again, for infinity because ref_isales_id = [1].ref_isales_id and the condition for your while loop is never met.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it!

```
private void manageBalancesTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                 
    payBtn.setEnabled(true);
    historyBtn.setEnabled(true);
    try{
        int row = manageBalancesTable.getSelectedRow();
        clickedTable = (manageBalancesTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        conn = MySQLConnect.ConnectDB();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select isales_id,rce,total_payment,pay_status,pay_amount,remaining_bal,it_id,client_id,ic_id,ref_isales_id from installation_sales where (isales_id='"+clickedTable+"' or ref_isales_id='"+clickedTable+"') and pay_status!='full payment' order by isales_id desc limit 1");

        if(rs.next()) {
            isales_id=rs.getString("isales_id");
            rce=rs.getString("rce");
            total_payment=rs.getDouble("total_payment");
            pay_status=rs.getString("pay_status");
            pay_amount1=rs.getDouble("pay_amount");
            remaining_bal=rs.getDouble("remaining_bal");
            it_id=rs.getInt("it_id");
            client_id=rs.getString("client_id");
            ic_id=rs.getString("ic_id");
            ref_isales_id=rs.getString("ref_isales_id");
        }

        while (!"0".equals(ref_isales_id)) {
            st2 = conn.createStatement();
            rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select isales_id,rce,total_payment,pay_status,pay_amount,remaining_bal,it_id,client_id,ic_id,ref_isales_id from installation_sales where ref_isales_id='"+isales_id+"' and pay_status!='full payment'  order by isales_id desc limit 1");
            if(rs2.next()) {
                isales_id=rs2.getString("isales_id");
                rce=rs2.getString("rce");
                total_payment=rs2.getDouble("total_payment");
                pay_status=rs2.getString("pay_status");
                pay_amount1=rs2.getDouble("pay_amount");
                remaining_bal=rs2.getDouble("remaining_bal");
                it_id=rs2.getInt("it_id");
                client_id=rs2.getString("client_id");
                ic_id=rs2.getString("ic_id");
                ref_isales_id=rs2.getString("ref_isales_id");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManageBalancesPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    if(null!=pay_status) switch (pay_status) {
        case "reservation fee":
            paymentStatusComboBox.removeAllItems();
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("select payment status...");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("down payment");
            paymentAmountTextField.setText("");
            break;
        case "down payment":
            paymentStatusComboBox.removeAllItems();
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("select payment status...");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("installment");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("full payment");
            paymentAmountTextField.setText("");
            break;
        case "installment":
            paymentStatusComboBox.removeAllItems();
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("select payment status...");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("installment");
            paymentStatusComboBox.addItem("full payment");
            paymentAmountTextField.setText("");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```